How can I prevent async/await to propagate my entire function calls in Node.js?
I have a problem I could not find the solution for.
I want to connect to the Postgres database in Node and run some queries.
The client.connect() is an async method. Thus I have to await it. But as soon as I use await I should make my own getFromDatabase method async.
And when I change my own getFromDatabase method async, then I should await it in my getCourses method. And this goes on and the entire code is pollutted with boilerplate await/async keywords.
How can I manage that? How can I await only for the client.connect() method?

You mean you want to synchronously wait for asynchronous result? If yes, than that's not possible. And why do you consider using async-await syntax as bad/unreadable code? The hole point of async-await is to make asynchronous code more readable and make it look like synchronous code.

@Yousaf, I'm writing APIs and from the API call to the database, every call and every method should become awai/async. Of course that's boilerplate. What is boilerplate? When something is repetitively written when it can be ommitted. Let's say I had a config to tell Node.js that this app is all await/async. What would be different?

Almost 10 years old but ever relevant: What Color is Your Function?

@jtbandes the thread you linked is hard for me to understand.
